# NetSuite - add custom lines to purchase order

Tags: php, netsuite

I want to add a custom lines, like PO lines, to PO Object. The parent of these custom lines should be the PO. I also want to display them just like PO lines (in a separate block).

Comment: what do you mean by `in a separate block`. Did you mean to display in a separate `subtab` ?

Comment: Yes. I want to have a tab "just like PO Lines" and under that i want have my line details. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom record called PO Lines. The first field you would need is "Parent PO" (choose your own name) of type Transaction and this field should be checked as parent. Add the other fields you desire for your custom lines

You will then need to build the subtab and use this record.

You haven't mentioned how these lines create so:
If user creation make sure your intended audience has the necessary privileges for create & edit of this new record
If script creation, you would just set the Parent PO to whatever PO you want it on based on your business logic